# TodayWidget built correctly but com.apple.springboard running

Tags: ios, ios10, today-extension

My todayWidget was developed for iOS 8 (and worked on it) and was a very simple todayWidget that only fetch data from a server in the widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler method, and print it.

When I updated my project from Xcode7 to Xcode8 and tested my todayWidget on ios8 and 10 devices and simulator, I got a weird behavior.

When I launch the TodayWidget target, Xcode build successfully, and then i got

[image]

It tells me it didn't launch my extension but "com.apple.springboard"

The strange thing is, that when I uninstall my app, the today widget disappear from the widget selection screen. Then , I run the extension target, the app installs successfully , I got the "running com.apple.springboard", my widget does appear in the widget selection screen, but when I move it in left or right column, it doesn't appear at all on my widget screen and the extension isn't listed in the "attach to process" list in XCode.

When I run the target, and go to the debug navigation tab in Xcode, it only tells me "waiting to attach" and nothing ever attach to it.

I downloaded a previous version of Xcode (since I thought it was due to the fact that I upgraded XCode from 7 to 8) but the problem seems to appear every time now.

My deployment target is set to iOS8.

and my scheme seems to be correct.

I got the problem on devices and simulator as well.

has anyone encounter this problem before ?

Comment: I tried to delete my extension from my project and then create a new one, with an hello world message.  I just created it and I got the same result. the process doesn't exist, and I got the "running com.apple.springboard" message

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same behaviour. My iPod was on iOS 9.3, my application targeted 8.0 and my widget 10.2. I just set my targets on 9.3 for my widget and my application and my widget finally appeared.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to **change bundle ID**. 
It was needed because I already have widget extension with the same name before, which was later deleted but obviously registered somewhere on Apple's side.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added widget dependency on the main app.

Go to Main Project Target -
Build Phases - Dependencies - < Add widget dependency >